# check_ssh returning Permission denied

Tags: linux, nagios, nrpe

I'm a long time Nagios fan, like 15 years. In one of my environments, I have Nagios and NRPE running on several Linux hosts and everything has been working as expected for several months. I recently added 3 Linux 8 (Rocky) hosts into the environment... All 3 are identically configured, with NRPE installed, and the Nagios server is monitoring 8 of 9 services on all 3 hosts without issue.

But check_ssh is **not** working on 2 of the 3 hosts.  From the Nagios server:

```
[root@nagios ~]# /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H 192.168.0.71 -c check_ssh
SSH OK - OpenSSH_8.0 (protocol 2.0) | time=0.011923s;;;0.000000;10.000000

[root@nagios ~]# /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H 192.168.0.72 -c check_ssh
connect to address 192.168.0.69 and port 22: Permission denied

[root@nagios ~]# /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H 192.168.0.73 -c check_ssh
connect to address 192.168.0.69 and port 22: Permission denied
```

I am able to run check_ssh as root and as the nrpe user on the 2 "bad" hosts:

```
[root@192.168.0.72 ~]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_ssh -H 192.168.0.69
SSH OK - OpenSSH_8.0 (protocol 2.0) | time=0.011192s;;;0.000000;10.000000
[root@192.168.0.72 ~]# runuser -u nrpe -- /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_ssh -H 192.168.0.69
SSH OK - OpenSSH_8.0 (protocol 2.0) | time=0.010463s;;;0.000000;10.000000

[root@192.168.0.73 ~]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_ssh -H 192.168.0.69
SSH OK - OpenSSH_8.0 (protocol 2.0) | time=0.010107s;;;0.000000;10.000000
[root@192.168.0.73 ~]# runuser -u nrpe -- /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_ssh -H 192.168.0.69
SSH OK - OpenSSH_8.0 (protocol 2.0) | time=0.010427s;;;0.000000;10.000000
```

And there are no problems running ssh between the hosts and nagios (or to any other host in the environment).

Suggestions?

Comment: what is the ip of `nagios`?

Comment: ip of nagios is 192.168.0.69

Comment: have you checked log/journal for selinux errors?

Comment: Getting this on one of the "bad" hosts:

type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1662920839.814:144687): arch=c000003e syscall=42 success=no exit=-13 a0=3 a1=562d602923c0 a2=10 a3=0 items=0 ppid=105120 pid=105121 auid=4294967295 uid=989 gid=989 euid=989 suid=989 fsuid=989 egid=989 sgid=989 fsgid=989 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="check_ssh" exe="/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_ssh" subj=system_u:system_r:nrpe_t:s0 key=(null)ARCH=x86_64 SYSCALL=connect AUID="unset" UID="nrpe" GID="nrpe" EUID="nrpe" SUID="nrpe" FSUID="nrpe" EGID="nrpe" SGID="nrpe" FSGID="nrpe"

Comment: no `denied` journal entries, only this?

Comment: and can you try if it works if you temporarily disable selinux (`setenforce 0`)?

Comment: Seeing allot of these:

type=AVC msg=audit(1662923463.087:144976): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=105461 comm="check_ssh" dest=22 scontext=system_u:system_r:nrpe_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:ssh_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket permissive=0

Comment: Oh, "setenforce 0" worked!  What should I do now to get it working without that?

Comment: how did you install nagios/nrpe on those new hosts?

Comment: I used Yum...  did not build NRPE, it was available through Yum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely SELinux is blocking NRPE, as demonstrated by it working with `setenforce 0`.

Verify you have the `nrpe-selinux` package installed.

Comment: I've installed it but the command is still failing without "setenforce 0".  Is there something else to do after installing nrpe-selinux?

Comment: hrm, not that i know of.

Comment: IDK what happened, but I tried this again and "setenforce 0" solved the problem.  Thanks!